# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

I am getting an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at listItems"(app.js:73)
I haven't been able to identify what is tripping it up, but virtually I wanted to make two inputs into the "person" and "place" input fields, then press a button to insert them.

The HTML:

```
 <template id="mylist.html">
    <ons-page id='mylist'>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-toolbar-button onclick="fn.open()">
            <ons-icon icon="md-menu"></ons-icon>
          </ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          My List
        </div>
        
      </ons-toolbar>
      <div>
      
        <ons-input type="text" class="select-input--underbar" id="person" placeholder="Enter person here . . ."></ons-input>

        <ons-input type="text" class="select-input--underbar" id="place" placeholder="Enter place here . . ."></ons-input>
        
        <ons-button modifier="large" onclick="addItem()">Add Item</ons-button>
     
      </div>
      
      
      
    
      <ons-list id='stuffList'>
        <ons-list-header>Listed Items:</ons-list-header>
        <ons-list-item>

        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
     
      
    </ons-page>
  </template>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function openDb() {
db = openDatabase('Stuff1', '1', 'StuffV', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
                   //(Database Name, Version, Display Name, Size )

db.transaction(function (tx) {   
   tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stuffLogs (id unique, person TEXT, place TEXT)"); 

  });
}

document.addEventListener('init', function(event) {
  if(event.target.id == 'mylist') {
    openDb();
    storeItems();
  }
});

function gotError(tx, error) {
  console.error('Something went wrong.', error);
}

function gotSuccess(tx) {
  storeItems()
}

function addItem() 
{
  var textbox = document.getElementById("person", "place");
  var value = textbox.value;

  db.transaction(function(tx)
  {
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO stuffLogs (person,place) VALUES (?,?)", [value], gotSuccess, gotError)
  });

  textbox.value = "";
  fn.load("mylist.html");
}

function storeItems()
{
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM stuffLogs", [], listItems, gotError);
  });
}

function listItems(tx, rs)
{
  var output = '';
  var stuffList = document.getElementById('stuffList');

  for(i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++)
  {
    output += renderItems(rs.rows.item(i));
  }

  foodList.innerHTML = output;

}

function renderItems(row)
{
  return "ons-list-item>" + row.stuffLogs +
  "<div class=\"right\"> <ons-button><ons-icon icon=\"trash\"></ons-icon></ons-button></div>" +
  "</ons-list-item>";
}
```

Line 73:

```
for(i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++)
  {
    output += renderItems(rs.rows.item(i));
  }

  foodList.innerHTML = output;

}
```

I could've easily overlooked something as I'm still learning JavaScript, so any guidance or answer to this problem would help.

Comment: What does your `rs` object look like?  Seems it doesn't have `rows` like you are expecting.

Comment: I actually just fixed my previous issue, but I am now met with              
"SQLError {code: 5, message: "number of '?'s in statement string does not match argument count"}"                                                                                                      as my error instead. Even with two inputs and two columns being stated.

Comment: `tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO stuffLogs (person,place) VALUES (?,?)", [value], gotSuccess, gotError)` you only define one value here

Comment: Ah, this does make sense looking at it now. I have now successfully inserted both contents into the db, but I am getting "ons-list-item>undefined" printed to my list instead of what it says in the db. Progress in a way, but new problems.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling `listItems` on the result of the sql query.  If the sql result does not contain rows then the code will throw like you posted. Do a check in `listItems` to make sure rows is an array and exit early if not.

```
if (!Array.isArray(rs.rows)) {
  return;
}
```